# Android studio instant-run not work well

Tags: android, android-studio, instant-run

I use the Android studio 2.0, and configure the project with the [official doc](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run) , the config of `instant run` in the setting window of AS has changed from disabled to enabled state. As well the run icon has lightning now，but when i change the code, just add a toast in a function, and click the lightning run, the application will be exit, and log show like below:

```
11-24 19:59:40.382 20951-20957/com.ss.android.essay.joke I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
11-24 19:59:40.383 20951-20957/com.xxx I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
11-24 19:59:40.475 4922-14521/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{651bd86 u0 com.ss.android.essay.joke/com.xxx.MainActivity}
```

Edit：The status of bug has updated，crash not happened again with alpha2，but still can't use instant-run， more detail：https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195064

`Edit: Android studio 2.1.1 with 2.12 gradle work well now.`

Comment: you know AS 2.0 is still a preview with thousand of possible bugs... right?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla ha, I know, after a successful test with the sample project, i really want it worked with my develop project too.

Comment: What exactly are you changing in your code for Instant Run.  Just adding Toast notifications?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes. Adding toast notification in an instance method.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) SO answer

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your change is *not* covered by Instant Run, check out [Android tools site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) for a list of supported hot swap actions:
[image]

Comment: why not covered? The code change is just adding a toast in the instance method. As well, it work in the sample project.

Comment: It's still in development, there are still plenty of rooms to grow and bugs to squash. If you believe this is a bug then you can file a bug report: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: @Kai Why are you assuming his change is not covered by Instant Run?